# how to json_decode raw json data?

Tags: php, arrays, json

if i use this link: http://socialgraph.apis.google.com/lookup?q=twitter.com&fme=1&edi=1&edo=1&pretty=1&callback=twitter i get:

```
twitter({
"canonical_mapping": {
"twitter.com": "http://twitter.com/"
},
"nodes": {
"http://twitter.com/": {
"attributes": {
 "fn": "Mysteriously Unnamed"
},
"claimed_nodes": [
],
"unverified_claiming_nodes": [
"http://7502112.appspot.com/aldiRN",
"http://a.danteng.me/BimaVii",
"http://a.danteng.me/iamsccb",
"http://a.danteng.me/kuiperdagne",
"http://a.danteng.me/lezzchow",
.....
```

how can i read through this?

i've tryed

```
$link = 'http://socialgraph.apis.google.com/lookup?q=exploretalent.com%2F&fme=1&edi=1&edo=1&pretty=1&callback=exploretalent';
$socialapi = @file_get_contents($link);
$social_api = json_decode($socialapi, true);
var_dump ($social_api);
```

but i get :`<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>`

is there a way to convert it to an array?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch off the callback - it's turning the JSON into JSONP that tries to call a JS function `twitter()`, passing the data to it.

This URL should be convertable by json_decode just fine: http://socialgraph.apis.google.com/lookup?q=twitter.com&fme=1&edi=1&edo=1&pretty=1

In fact, the 'pretty' parameter isn't relevant either. This is raw json and should work best: http://socialgraph.apis.google.com/lookup?q=twitter.com&fme=1&edi=1&edo=1

Comment: success. thanks. it doesn't matter if i leave the `pretty` element there. looks like it still works.

Comment: @Patrioticcow I'd recommend that you remove it: it will add whitespace overhead to your bandwidth and theirs.